# Name for a specific kind of regular hyper graphs

Tags: terminology, hypergraph

**Question:**
is there already an established name for the following kind of hypergaphs:
given a set $\mathfrak{V}$ with $n\lt\infty$ elements

- the hyper vertices $\mathfrak{v}\subseteq \mathfrak{V}$ are the subsets of $\mathfrak{V}$ with $\mathrm{card}(\mathfrak{v})=k\le n$
- the hyper-edges are the unordered pairs $\lbrace\mathfrak{u},\mathfrak{v}\rbrace:\ \mathrm{card}\left(\mathfrak{u}\cup\mathfrak{v}\right)=k+1\,\mathrm{card}\left(\mathfrak{u}\cap\mathfrak{v}\right)=k-1$

I am looking for an established name to increase the chance of finding related publication.

Comment: This seems like the [Johnson graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph) $J(n,k)$, whose vertices are the $k$-subsets of $[n]$, and with an edge joining two sets iff they intersect in $k-1$ elements.